# how to calculate the value of a variable?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to know how to take an equation with a variable and have it calculate and output the value of said variable. example of the equation.

2900 = 1 * T * ((52 + 6) / 12)

I need the program to take all values and give me the value of 'T'. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Passing an argument/parameter and returning a processed value. Literally Get/Set of any object. But really have you done any programming?

Comment: Yes I have but I have never had to do anything that involved this kind of thing before.

Comment: I am puzzled. The smallest programme would talk about getting an input from a user, setting it to a variable and outputting it. Can you please take a C# tutorial of how to write at least a console programme? [tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Development-Class/InputfromtheconsoleusingReadLine.htm)

In the above tutorial `str` can be your `T`. Next you could either output:

`Console.WriteLine("You calculated result: " + 1*T((52+6)/12));` 

Frankly if you intend to go forward, learn some programming basics. Some c# reference [headfirst c#](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfcsharp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rearrange the equation  to the form T=....

```
2900 = 1 * T * ((52 + 6) / 12)
```

becomes (for example)

```
T = 2900/(52 + 6) * 12 / 1
```

Next replace the  number with variables

```
T = a/(b + c) * d / e
```

then you write a function to calculate T given a-e

```
double T(double a, double b, double b, double c, double d, double e) {
 return  a/(b + c) * d / e;
}
```

then you use it like this

```
double T = T(2900, 52, 6, 12, 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

If equation is the same, only parameters change - then just rearrange it to a variable.

If whole equation is a user input, then it is getting ugly quick ("2*cos(log(x^3)) = - e^tg(x)") and there is no silver bullet.
Easiest thing you can do is evaluate it at runtime (for example with [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/)) and "bruteforce" the solutions.